# Adding new relationship to an imported GORM class

Tags: grails, orm, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

Is there a way to add more belongs-to relationships to an imported GORM domain class? Specifically, I'm attempting to use table-per-class to extend a shared subclass, but if I do this in two (or more) locations, and the locations do not have knowledge of each-other then things like:

```
set.addToParents(parentSet)
```

Start leading to:

```
org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=3482] was not of the specified subclass [com.acumenllc.domaincore.DbSet] : Discriminator: com.acumenllc.tickets.domain.TicketSet
```

happening everywhere.

A little more background, I'm working on a closure table to keep track of related objects. The base class recognizes the parent-child bi-directional relationship, as well as the ancestor-descendant extension of it. Different applications then extend this class with belongsTo relationships on objects to be represented as nodes in the resultant graph. We specifically want to be able to more-or-less ignore some of these other classes in other applications that happen to share the same database.

Ideally, it would be possible to import our base domain class into a new application and, rather than extending into a subclass, re-define the set of relationships that the base class recognizes in the scope of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only practical way I can see of doing this is with .hbm.xml files. The GORM approach of including `hasMany`/`belongsTo` in the code and JPA's approach using annotations are both fairly inflexible to support this sort of mapping. But if you separate the configuration from the code, you can define the relationships for different applications however you like. Creating a hibernate.cfg.xml file and the hbm.xml files is described [here in the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/hibernate.html).